# Windows Linux Subsystem GIT showing changes when not changed

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For some reason Ubuntu installed as a Windows subsystem on Windows 10 thinks that there is changes to a file when there is not in GIT. Is there a solution to this?

In the below picture, modifications were made to the ConnectedToolsController but not to the postman collection. The WSL should look like the GitBash cmd prompt.

[image]

Comment: this is basically a case of mounted repository, which is said many times is not a supported case.

Comment: I feel like this is a question that belongs on SuperUser, since this is primarily about the WSL

Comment: @Jeeter yes I just forgot the name of SuperUser, sorry

Comment: No problem, just flag a moderator and see if they can migrate the question

Comment: This question may be valid in SO because this is related to Git & `\r\n`. check this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because git does not support being on a mounted disc.